# Error importing PyQt4.QtCore

Tags: python, pyqt4, python-sip

I've been trying to get some GUI apps based on PyQt to run.

Somewhere in the PPython scripts is the following import:

`from PyQt4.QtCore import *`

This is the error that I keep getting consistently.

RuntimeError: the sip module implements API v8.0 to v8.1 but the PyQt4.QtCore module requires API v7.1

Why is this happening? How do I get sip to use the right API?

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like your sip and PyQt4 packages are not compatible. What OS are you using? Did you install from source or binary packages?

Comment: Hi, I'm using Ubuntu 10.04, and installed the source packages.

Comment: Which versions are you using? I'd suggest grabbing the latest SIP and PyQt versions from riverbankcomputing.com and giving it another go.